# Android Emulator unusable slow

Tags: android, performance, simulator

for a PhoneGap Project I need a running Android Emulator.
So installed from the official Android website and try to run... but this thing is so slow, that development is impossible.

I run it under OS X Lion on 27inch iMac, 12 GB RAM Core i5 and SSD.

Is there any trick getting this thing run?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no trick. Emulators are really slow. The best solution possible is to use a real device.

Answer (score 0):

Android simulator is quite useable as long as you do not play with HC/ICS/JB (however things are getting better and better with each release) or you do not play with OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

I use a real device fro development, but if you realy want to use the emulator here are some tips;

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm